# Dojo abort drag/drop operation in dnd/drop/before

Tags: javascript, dojo, drag-and-drop

I wanted to know if there is a way I can abort the default drop operation in dojo. I am doing some custom manipulation in the function,

```
dojo.subscribe("/dnd/drop/before", function(source, nodes, iscopy){
     //Custom manipulation
});
```

And from this function, I want to cancel the drop, similar to what happens when you press the Esc Key?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can publish the topic `dnd/cancel`, i.e. `dojo.publish('/dnd/cancel')`, then call `dojo.dnd.manager().stopDrag()` to cancel the drop.

But the recommended way is to customize the `checkAcceptance()` of `dojo.dnd.Source` to return `false` when current node is not droppable. Find more details in dojo dnd's [doc](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/dnd).

Answer (score 1):

For me, overriding `onDrop` works like a charm. Accourding to [doc](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/dnd#source), i have something like:

```
var source2 = new dojo.dnd.Source("source", {
        onDrop : function(source, nodes, copy) {
            if (canProceedCondition) {
                this.onDropExternal(source, nodes, copy);
            }           
        }
    });
```